# Can't click "Select Images" into Gallery of Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, image, file-upload, gallery

I am working with a wordpress website and I have an issue  I Can't click "Select Images" into Gallery of Wordpress. how to fix it ?
Please help me. thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have to contact the plugin developper...
Not easy to help you without the code